# jQuery: .select() and .focus() method difference

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, what is basic difference between `.select()` & `focus()` and what are their appropriate using places?

Comment: -1 because the documentation is quite good in this case and the question title does not convey the question. I'd liked to see that latter part of the question emphasized more and with some example situations where the distinction between the two methods have been unclear to you.

Comment: whatever man, the question helped me and was exactly what I needed. upvote!

Comment: +1, helped me too.  Sometimes this place is better than trawling through docs.

Comment: A note from developer.mozilla:
Calling element.select() will not necessarily focus the input, so it is often used with HTMLElement.focus()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They have their differences:

- **`.select()`**: will fire when TEXT is selected.

  - Limitted to `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements.
- **`.focus()`**: will fire when an element receives focus i.e. an input box is clicked on, tabbed into, etc.

  - Also limitted but to a wider range of elements, mostly form elements such as `<input>`, `<select>`, `<a>`

Comment: Confirmed in modern browsers: If you trigger _select()_ on an input, it will also fire _focus_ event on that same input.

Answer (score 7):

From the jQuery documentation:

**[select](http://api.jquery.com/select)**

> The select event is sent to an element
>   when the user makes a text selection
>   inside it. This event is limited to
>   `<input type="text">`fields and
>   `<textarea>` boxes.

**[focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)**

> The focus event is sent to an element
>   when it gains focus. This event is
>   implicitly applicable to a limited set
>   of elements, such as form elements
>   (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links
>   (`<a href>`). In recent browser
>   versions, the event can be extended to
>   include all element types by
>   explicitly setting the element's
>   tabindex property.