# onkeyup not working in iOS 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios10, onkeyup

I am working that works something like a four digit pin. The best way I found to achieve this was onkeyup function which works great on android but unfortunately it doesn't work on iOS. I'm implementing it something like this:

```
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="pp1" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this, 'pp2', '')" />
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="pp2" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this, 'pp3', 'pp1')" />
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="pp3" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this, 'pp4', 'pp2')" />
<input type="password" maxlength=1 id="pp4" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this, '', 'pp3')" />
```

and my script looks like this:

```
function moveOnMax(field, nextFieldID, prevFieldID) {
    if (field.value != '') {
        if (field.value.length == 1) {
            document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById(prevFieldID).focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the  "touchend" event to make this work. Something like this in your JavaScript.

var el = document.getElementsByID("pp1");

el.addEventListener("touchend", myevent, false);

And that should work.

Comment: touchend might not do for me here since I want to move the cursor to the next input only when user types something in the previous one.

Comment: Although I did something like this but failed :( `document.getElementById('pp1').addEventListener("keyup", function ()` `{`
                `//alert('key up')`
                `document.getElementById('pp2').focus();`
            `}, false);`

Comment: Can you get a console log on keyup on iOS?

Comment: Okay so this is what I did, I created a simple onkeyup func on an input and called a simple alert and used a jquery .focus() func to move the cursor to the next input as soon as user types anything and got the alert back but I can't figure why .focus() isnt working :( P.S It works perfect on android and on iOS < 10.0

Comment: try .select(), They both do similar but i find focus causes me some trouble. here is a link to explain the 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263424/jquery-select-and-focus-method-difference